# How do i get returned value from inner Thread Runnable method in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading

How do i assign `Status` with `CallMe()` using `isFinish()` to have returned value true?

```
public static boolean isFinish ()
{    
  boolean Status = false;
  new Thread(new Runnable()
  {
    public void run()
    {
      /* This shell return true or false 
       * How do you keep it in Status
       */
      CallMe(); 
    }
  }).start();

  /* How can i get the true or false exactly from CallMe? here */
  return Status;
}

public static boolean CallMe()
{
  /* some heavy loads ... */
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Why using thread at all? The start() will create a separate thread of execution and at that point isFinish will continue its execution.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There are two ways of doing this.
The first is to use a future computation result and the other is to have a shared variable.
I think that the first method is much cleaner than the second, but sometimes you need to push values to the thread too.

- Using a `RunnableFuture`.

`FutureTask` implements a `RunnableFuture`. So you create that task which, once executed, will have a value.

```
RunnableFuture f = new FutureTask(new Callable<Boolean>() {
  // implement call
});
// start the thread to execute it (you may also use an Executor)
new Thread(f).start();
// get the result
f.get();
```

- Using a holder class

You create a class holding a value and share a reference to that class. You may create your own class or simply use the `AtomicReference`.
By holder class, I mean a class that has a public modifiable attribute.

```
// create the shared variable
final AtomicBoolean b = new AtomicBoolean();
// create your thread
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    // you can use b in here
  }
});
t.start();
// wait for the thread
t.join();
b.get();
```

Comment: +1, like two methods, really thanks. I needed to have full-duplex both gives me the best direction.

Comment: thank you! I needed this for my university project, you helped a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You rewrite the code to use `Callable<Boolean>` and obtain a `Future` when launching the `Runnable`.

Futures allow the launching thread to properly check that the value is ready and read it asynchronously.  You could do the coding by hand, but since `Future` is now part of the standard JVM libraries, why would you (outside of a programming class)?

Answer (score 0):

Working with raw threads, you could implement Runnable with a named type, and store the value in it.

```
class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
   boolean status;

   public void run() {
      ...
   }
}
```

However, if you're working with another thread, you'll have to synchronize in some way.

It would be easier to use the higher-level tools provided by the java.util.concurrent hierarchy. You can submit a Callable to an Executor, and get a Future. You can ask the Future if it's done, and get the result. There's an [Oracle tutorial here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/exinter.html).