# Returning data from class which implement interface in short form(Construction)

Tags: java, multithreading, interface

I have simple question but can't find good and completed answer in internet, how write construction for returning result, which can be calling in short form.
For example I'have main method when i'm check true/false conditions

```
MyInterface checker;
public static void main(String s[]){
checker = new ClassWhichImplementedInterface();
    if (checker.isTrueState())
      //code
    else
      //code
    }
```

Result state is checked in another thread, and i must wait some time for executing this statement result.
What the construction must have MyInterface and ClassWhichImplementedInterface? 
For more completed version of question if, for example, my ClassWhichImplementedInterface have already another implementation (Runnable etc...), what will be better implementing two interfaces in ClassWhichImplementedInterface or my MyInterface must be extended from Runnable?
Thx.

**UPD:** clarify my question: what methods i must to have for realized
my state conditioncheck in main method/class, for example in interface must be presented next method

```
public interface MyInterface(){
   public boolean isTrueState();
}
```

My ClassWhichImplementedInterface must be the next, for example:

```
public class ClassWhichImplementedInterface implements Runnable,MyInterface{
...
    @Override
   public void run(){
        try {
            Thread.currentThread().sleep(6000);
            return true/false;  //// this statement i want return when check isTrueState in main method
        }catch (Exception e){}
    }
...
}
```

Comment: Could you clarify your question(s)?

Comment: Your question is very unclear, but it seems you're looking for `Future`.

Comment: JB Nizet, Yes and no. I'm try to refactor my code. There are many kind place where this type of realization will be very comfortable for using

Comment: I think you want to use a `Future`.

Comment: i try Future but the main thread freezing (example from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7714432/how-do-i-get-returned-value-from-inner-thread-runnable-method-in-java) 
actually i don't understand how, how background thread can freeze main thread... i test it's on android